# Slick grid values not populating in the grid

Tags: slickgrid, slick.js

I am trying to populate slick grid it is showing the values while debugging but not showing in the web page.

I have added all the required references. Here is the js function.

```
function LoadMonthStatus(dropdownYear, buttonId) {
 try {
    $(".screen").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
    $(".slick-cell").css({ opacity: 0.5 });

    dirtyFlag = false;
    var drpYear = document.getElementById(dropdownYear);
    year = drpYear.options[drpYear.selectedIndex].value;
    data = [];
    var dropdownoptions = ""; // "hard,soft,closed";
    var columns = {};
    var options = { 
        editable: true,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: false,
        autoEdit: true,
        autoHeight: true
    };

    columns = [
        { id: "month", name: "Month", field: "Month", width: 250 },
        { id: "status", name: "Close Status", field: "Status", options: columnOptions, editor: Slick.Editors.Select, width: 150 }
    ];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:51072/PULSE.Service/api/MonthCloseStatus/LoadMonths",
        data: { year: $("#drpYear").val() },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            data = msg;
            monthStatusGrid = new Slick.Grid("#slkgrdMonths", data, columns, options);
            //grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());
            monthStatusGrid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                var cell = monthStatusGrid.getCellNode(args.row, args.cell);
                cell.className += cell.className ? ' slick-cell-modified' : 'slick-cell-modified';
                dirtyFlag = true;
            });
            if (msg == null || msg == "")
                document.getElementById(buttonId).disabled = true;
            else
                document.getElementById(buttonId).disabled = false;
            //Enable the button

            $(".screen").css({ opacity: 1 });
            $(".slick-cell").css({ opacity: 1 });

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            try {
                var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                jAlert(err.Message, 'PULSE');
            }
            catch (e) {
                jAlert(clientErrMessage, 'PULSE');
            }
            $(".screen").css({ opacity: 1 });
            $(".slick-cell").css({ opacity: 1 });

        }
    });
  }
  catch (e) {
    jAlert(clientErrMessage, 'PULSE');
  }
}
```

Slick grid should be populated with months like Jan, Feb, March and its status respectively in 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables to give an answer. However I would recommend that you create the grid on page load and just populate it with data on ajax load, rather than creating the grid possibly each time.
In my experience, data not being visible is often CSS related.

Have a look at the samples in the SlickGrid repo, they are pretty comprehensive. Make sure you are using https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid rather than the old MLeibman repo.

If you want assistance, the best idea is to create a stand alone test page that works with local files (apart from the ajax call) in the example folder of the slickgrid repo.
If you can share that, we can easily reproduce the behaviour. As a bonus, about 90% of the time you'll work out the problem while you are creating the example page.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see
-if the property of data after ajax call is matching with the property provided in columns Field and vice versa.
- if the container u are passing is correct.